# Does Netty only register one ServerSocketChannel to one NioEventLoop?

Tags: java, netty

I use netty-all:4.1.42.Final
AbstractBootstrap line 311:

```java
ChannelFuture regFuture = config().group().register(channel);
```

config().group() is MultithreadEventLoopGroup, so register method should be:

```
class MultithreadEventLoopGroup{
   public ChannelFuture register(Channel channel) {
      return next().register(channel);
   }
}
```

When config().group() has more NioEventLoop, but only one can be used.

Netty can't support multiple Selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you `register()` it will pick the next `EventLoop` to register the `Channel` to it. This means if you for example have an `EventLoopGroup` with  8 `EventLoop`s and call `register` (or `bind`) 8 times each of the `Channel`s will use another `EventLoop` (and so `Selector`).